# IIS 8.5 - Default URL redirection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have deployed MVC5 project that I converted to the application under Default Web Site as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5Lt3.png). I think, this is a standard procedure. When I open the default URL http://**intranet.company.com** the server do a redirection to http://**172.20.20.133/intranet/**. Physical path of the intranet application is **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet**. I also tried to move deployed project directly under Default Web Site without any virtual directory but with the same result, it was redirected to http://**172.20.20.133/intranet/**.

Somebody knows what's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do the iis bindings look like

Comment: Here's the site binding settings http://imgur.com/a/O8G6k